# PyTorch pretrained model(weights=False vs weights= True)

Tags: python, pytorch

I am little stuck in understanding the difference between `squeezenet1_1 = models.squeezenet1_1(weights=False`) vs `squeezenet1_1 = models.squeezenet1_1(weights=True)`....

If I want to build my own image classifier with my own custom data (etc. person wearing a helmet, person wearing a bag, person wearing glasses...),
I should set `squeezenet1_1 = models.squeezenet1_1(weights=False)`.
Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `weights` argument refers to whether the model is initialized with pre-trained weights, then generally yes. It's beneficial to initialize with a pretraining task when performing fine-tuning on a downstream task.

Comment: Thanks I have two more questions if possible
1. Even though I set weights = True, I can still build my own classifier and run it with a webcam, USB camera right? 
2. Just the accuracy of model changes due to weights= True or False right?. All the process is the same as weights = True? I saw some tutorial videos about PyTorch fine tuning, but I cannot really find a video or tutorial that shows /use weight (or pretrained) =False)...

Comment: 1. Yes you can always finetune your pre-trained model on a different task/dataset altogether. 2. Yes the accuracy of the model will change depending on the initialization of the weights. Depending on the domain gap, pre-trained weights should converge faster than with random initialization. But it all depends on the task at hand.